# Generate Windows Compatible Binary from Xcode C++ Console Application

Tags: c++, xcode, executable

I am using XCode for developing a C++ Console Application. After compiling XCode generates the Unix Executable File, which run on Mac perfectly. But doesn't work on windows. I have tried changing the active architecture as well from x86_64 to i386 but no luck.

Is it possible anyway to generate executable like Borland C, or Turbo C compilers does. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCode does not generate Windows binaries.  Processor architecture isn't the only thing that is different - executable format, names of import libraries, ABI, etc., etc.

Use a Windows compiler, like [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/), to generate a Windeows binary.

Answer (score 0):

Although the compiler will compile for different CPU architectures, building for another *OS* is not supported (with iOS being the exception).

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Deleted the second paragraph entirely... didn't really answer any question anyway.